# CSS transform div everything remains rotated

Tags: css, transform, skew

I'm rotating a set of divs with the following;

```
map-grid:
-webkit-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -o-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
```

this is to a create a kind of isometric grid. It works fine, however the content of each div I want to keep in the normal perspective so I tried;

```
map-grid-cell-content:
-webkit-transform: none; 
       -moz-transform: none; 
        -ms-transform: none; 
         -o-transform: none; 
            transform: none;
```

the markup is like this

```
<div class='map-container'>
  <div class='map-grid'>

    <div class="map-grid-cell-content">
       << this is where i need the content to be normal >>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

but everything remains rotated, any ideas, please?

Comment: The easiest way would be to make the properties of the child div opposite of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.map-grid {
  -webkit-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    -o-transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
    transform:skewX(-45deg) rotate(15deg) scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8) translateX(7em) translateY(-4.5em);
  margin-top: 300px;
  }
.map-grid-cell-content {
  transform: skewX(45deg) rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='map-container'>
  <div class='map-grid'>

    <div class="map-grid-cell-content">
       dwdwaddawwa
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

is this what you need?

Comment: Not quite as simple as the code you have above.  The thing that you didn't include is how to revert the scaleX and scaleY of the child elements.  This is actually done by dividing the initial value by 1 and then using that as the child elements property.  For example .map-grid {transform:scaleX(1.785) scaleY(.8);}  So the child div properties would be 1/1.785 and 1/.8   resulting in .map-grid-cell-content {transform:scaleX(0.56) scaleY(1.25);}  You would also need to add absolute positioning to the child element and in order to reverse translateX and translateY positioning.